# How to transmit custom data with an exception?

Tags: python-3.x

I am validating json request data for my service. There are many fields, each with their own validators. My plan is to turn the request into a frozen dataclass, if all validations are successful. A validation can fail for reasons that require additional data to explain the cause. If the request is invalid, I want to report this data back to the client so that the user knows why the request was unsuccessful.

Example: The request has a field with an array of fruit.

```
request = {
  'fruit': [{'type':'apple', 'price':5}, {'type': 'banana', 'price': 7}]
}
```

To validate the fruit field I use a function `validate_fruit(fruit: list)` which checks the types and values. If there is a fruit with price > 5 I say the request is invalid. I send a response with an error return code and want to specify which fruit is too expensive.

Example: Here, return code 12 means "there are fruit that are too expensive". Error data should give details.

```
response = {
  'return_code': 12
  'error_data': ['banana']
}
```

I would like to use exceptions to implement this. So `validate_fruit` can raise an Exception with a dict that specifies the return code and additional error data.

I am thinking about

```
def validate_fruit(fruit: list):
  failures = [elem['type'] for elem in fruit if elem['price'] > 5]
  if failures:
    raise ValueError(data={'error_data': failures, 'return_code': 12})

try:
  validate_fruit(fruit)
except Exception as error:
  if error.return_code == 12:
    ...
```

Has anyone had the same idea? How do you do this?

Comment: Your last code snippet is kinda wonky, it tries to raise an exception just to intercept it again. While I know what you mean I feel like it would be better to prototype that and put it on codereview.stackexchange.com , here on stackoverflow it's probably going to be closed as opinion based.

Comment: @syntonym I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like:

```
try:
    raise ValueError({'error_data': ['banana'], 'return_code': 12})
except Exception as ex:
    if ex.args[0]["return_code"] == 12:
        print("error 12")
```

Comment: Cool! I didn't know about the `args` attribute. Am I alone in using expections in this way?